# Create Firebird ODBC Connection from server

Tags: odbc, firebird

I don't have the skills for this, I tried some steps that I found on Google and forums, but I didn't get it.
I need to create ODBC connection on users machine, that can get access from Firebird database that it's located on a server (Windows Server 2008).

I already installed the ODBC driver and the client, both x64 from Firebird website.
I already gave access to TCP port (3050).

So, if I take the database file (.FDB) from the server and paste on the user machine, it works!
But I'd like to use the database file from the server itself.

So I tried to use IP and the path + file, but it can't connect (error below).
Can someone help me out please?

User will use the ODBC connection to connect in some softwares as Excel, ETL tools, PowerBI, etc.

Error:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you forgot to install and run Firebird Server service on your server machine. P.S. Character Set NONE is rather dangerous setting, you better set some charset native for your applications.

Comment: "get access from Firebird database" makes no sense. Database is just a file, it can not do a thing, in particular, database ifle can not access to client computers. What u actually need is client applications running at client computers connecting to Firebird Server running on the server computer. Also it seems ODBC driver is not actively mantained, there is commercial OLE DB provider, it might work better with Excel etc, but maybe not very much

Comment: @Arioch'The Thanks for the tips! Well I really don't know anyone who can help me out, even some friends that work with DB. So, can you help me with some more details? 1º: I will change the "Character Set". 2º: Can you send the link of the Firebird Server service? Because I thought I had already installed all. 3º: Where I found on Google, ODBC would be the best option now, but I can accept other options aswell, but anyway I'd like to try ODBC too. Really thanks!

Comment: https://firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/  you seem to install it on client computers (where full server installation is not really needed, only client part of the whole package was) but not on server computer. Or maybe you installed it on the server but did not run there.

Comment: Or you installed it on the server, but haven't configured the firewall to allow the port to be externally accessible.

Comment: I really don't know what to do more, I think I had tried all the options. To configure the firewall to be externally accessible is to add the port TCP 3050 right?

Comment: Read `firebird.conf` text file on server, maybe the is non-default port. Or maybe Firebird service was not started on the server computer, or maybe there is some other program running which took the 3050 port before Firebird could, or maybe Firebird command line was set to not use TCP/IP protocol (exotic but possible case). All in all you have to start with basic and generic TCP/IP diagnostic, making sure you can connect to the Firebird program on server computer from programs on client computers. WireShark, netstat, telnet, etc. Here is nothing FB-specific yet.

Comment: I took me over a week to get this done, we had to reinstall everything and changed the port to 3051 instead of 3050, somehow the 3050 port wasn't open to connect through TCP, but now it's workin, thanks for those advices.